# How to click on static text in applescript?

Tags: automation, applescript

I have a combo box that has a list as its child. This list has 2 children (they're static text) which are the options for the combo box.

My question is, is there a way to click on static text in applescript? If so, what is the syntax?
I've tried clicking on it (I don't get any errors) but nothing happens.

```
click static text 2 of list 1 of combo box 3 of UI element 0
```

Comment: Is this your own combo box, or are you using **System Events** to script another application’s GUI?  Note that you can edit your posts - deleting them is not the way to do it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using System Events

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the selected option of a combo box set the `value`

```
set value of combo box 3 of UI element 0 to "myOption"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly my combo box doesn't have a value. According to accessibility inspector, the selected option is whatever the title of the combo box is - if I manually click different options, the title changes to match the selected option. I've tried setting the title of the combo box to something different with applescript, but that throws an error

Comment: GUI scripting is a pain, take a look at the actions of the combo box, maybe there is a selection action. Or one of the attributes is settable.